# Tinymce how to float an image?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

By default in tinymce there are no image floating, only image, text alignment should I do it manually or there already are some plugins? can't find any...or how can I get the current selected elements and float them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can use `style_formats` option.
Document is here: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-formatting/#style_formats

> This option enables you to add more advanced style formats for text
>   and other elements to the editor. The value of this option will be
>   rendered as styles in the Formats dropdown.

You can go like this when you initialize a tinymce.

```
tinymce.init({
    ...
    style_formats: [
    {
        title: 'Image Left',
        selector: 'img',
        styles: {
            'float': 'left', 
            'margin': '0 10px 0 10px'
        }
     },
     {
         title: 'Image Right',
         selector: 'img', 
         styles: {
             'float': 'right', 
             'margin': '0 0 10px 10px'
         }
     }
]
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks this is what I've needed I'am new to tinymce...accept answer in 7 minutes :)

Comment: one more question, is there a way to add it as a button, not as a dropdown in the format menu?

Comment: @Rustam, Thanks. I'm not sure how to do it with a button. But it might be poosible with a `"Plugins with custom buttons"` http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin3x:style

Comment: "Image Left" and "Image Right" can be seen under Formats menu, when you use the toolbar option "styleselect" ( one might expect it to appear under "formatselect" toolbar option ).

Comment: I'm using ver.4.5.3 and the formats are not applied. nothing happen and the console return this error: Failed to execute 'setBaseAndExtent' on 'Selection': There is no child at offset 1.

Answer (score 6):

In TinyMce v4 and v5, when you have the `image` plugin in place,

```
plugins: [
    "... image"
],
```

then you can use the **image_class_list** property to allow the user to add classes to the images.

For instance, in the example below, the user makes the image float right, selecting the 'Right' option.
I have assigned to that option some TailwindCSS classes. The one that makes the image float is **float-right**.

```
image_class_list: [
    { title: 'Left', value: '' },
    { title: 'Right', value: 'w-full md:float-right' }
],
```

[image]

Here the official documentation of image_class_list:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/image/#image_class_list

If you want also to make the image float in the editor you also have to add the **content_style** property and assign the corresponding CSS attributes.

```
content_style: "body img.md\\:float-right{ float: right; }"
```

Here the official documentation of content_style:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_style